# Insert Content into specific place in Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I am trying to compare the string of two CSV files. If the string from the 2nd CSV file occurs in the 1st CSV file, the corresponding line in the 1st CSV file should be marked with a label (e.g.: "TestLabel") after the semicolon. The strings contain a lot of special characters. By and large, the comparison already works, I can also already add the label.

Since Powershell is still new to me and this is my first script, the following question still arises. How can I set my text "TestLabel" to a certain place in an uncomplicated way? Here, for example, in the next empty field between the semicolons?

CSV1 contains:

```
Testdefinition;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter
It is just a normal text (with round brackets).Test: success;ExistingLabel;;;;
This is a second text;;;
Another text;ExistingLabel;;;;
One more text for the testing - success;ExistingLabel;;;;
```

CSV2 contains:

```
Testdefinition;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter
It is just a normal text (with round brackets).Test: success
One more text for the testing - success
```

My script so far:

```
$header='Testdefinition', 'Stichwörter1', 'Stichwörter2', 'Stichwörter3', 'Stichwörter4', 'Stichwörter5'
$exportheader="Testdefinition;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter;Stichwörter"

$path1='D:\data\.....test.csv'
$path2='D:\data\.....test_failed.csv'

$wfile='temp1.csv'
$wfile2='temp2.csv'

Get-Content $path1 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $wfile -Encoding UTF8
Get-Content $path2 | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content $wfile2 -Encoding UTF8

$file1=Import-CSV -Path $wfile -Delimiter ";" -Header $header
$file2=Import-CSV -Path $wfile2 -Delimiter ";" -Header $header


$exportfile='test.csv'
#$exportfile=$file1

$file1 | Get-Member
$file2 | Get-Member

$file1 | Format-Table
$file2 | Format-Table

Write-Output ""
Write-Output "Searching for failed results"

Set-Content $exportfile -Value $exportheader

$file1.Testdefinition | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Output "The Testdefinition is: $_ "
    $testSearch = $_

    $testlinecontent = $file2.Testdefinition | Select-String $testSearch
    $testlinenumber = $testlinecontent.LineNumber

    if("$_" -eq "$testlinecontent")
    {
        Write-Output "Testline found: $testlinecontent in Line $testlinenumber"
        Write-Output "$_ = $testlinecontent"

        

        $testlineexport = "$_;$testlinenumber;TestLabel"

        Write-Output $testlineexport

        $testlineexport | Add-Content -Path $exportfile
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Output "Testline not found"
        $testlineexport = "$_;$testlinenumber;NULL"

        Write-Output $testlineexport
        $testlineexport | Add-Content -Path $exportfile
    }

    Write-Output ""
}

$exportCsv = Import-Csv $exportfile -Delimiter ";" -Header $header
$exportCsv | Format-Table

Remove-Item -Path $wfile
Remove-Item -Path $wfile2
```

I hope you can give me a hint. Thanks in advance!

Comment: As for your use of [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string): calling it for every line is quite inefficient; for in-memory matching use _operators_ (`-eq`, `-like`, `-match`). Also, as @SantiagoSquarzon has previously pointed out, in order to make `Select-String` search for _literal_ substrings, you must use the `-SimpleMatch` switch; by default, the (positionally implied) `-Pattern` argument is interpreted as a [regex](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the files aren't too big, you can use the following approach based on [`Compare-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object), which is conceptually clear and relatively simple:

```bash
# Read the CSV files into their header row and the array of data rows, as strings.
$header, $rows1 = Get-Content $path1
$null, $rows2 = Get-Content $path2

# Initialize the export file by writing its header
Set-Content -Encoding utf8 $exportfile -Value $exportheader

# Compare the data rows by their first ";"-separated field.
# If the fields match, append ";TestLabel" to the LHS data row before
# passing it through, otherwise pass it as-is, and append to the
# export file.
Compare-Object -PassThru $rows1 $rows2 -IncludeEqual -Property { $_.Split(';')[0] } |
  ForEach-Object { if ($_.SideIndicator -eq '==') { $_ + ';TestLabel' } else { $_ } } |
  Add-Content $exportfile
```

Note:

- For brevity I've omitted the code to also add a line number.
- As you are already aware, PowerShell doesn't support CSV files whose headers contain *duplicate* column names, given that the column names become *property names* on import, and must therefore be unique.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and sorry for the confusion of the 2 posts from me. Of course I didn't want to point out the same problem from the first post in the 2nd post, otherwise I wouldn't have made a 2nd post. For different questions, I like to make different post, just for a better overview for me.

Comment: Glad to hear the answer helped, @missim.